# Javascript not working (I guess...)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a little piece of simple javascript, using jQuery like so:

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    $("a.dropdown-toggle").on("mouseover", function() {
       console.log("yeah");
       $(this).dropdown("toggle");
    });

})(jQuery);
```

I will never understand why, when loaded in a separate file, it doesn't do anything, whereas when I copy/paste it in Chrome's console, it does exactly what I want.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Is the separate file referenced in the `<head></head>` section?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Perhaps if you give us a jsfiddle.net of what code you are working with we can help more

Comment: Maybe it didn't load all files yet... Try calling the function with `jQuery(function () {
    myFunction();
});`

Comment: did you add the script after your jquery libary? And where does this .dropdown come from?

Comment: Can you include all of the relevant `<script>` tags (in order), please? It might be that you're executing that code before the plugin is loaded.

Comment: check if jQuery is referenced already before your js file containing this code. OR, alternatively, you can refer jQuery file directly inside your js file, like:

place this line at the top of your js file.
/// <reference path="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" />

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your replies. I'm using wordpress. I've checked the loading order and jQuery (1.10.2) loads first, then Twitter Bootstrap, then my code. The `.dropdown` function comes from Bootstrap. I'll try to make a jsfiddle.